# Kibana - Parse Out / Aggregate Total Values Using Scripted Language

Tags: json, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

I need help to on how to parse out / aggregate the "hours worked" that are captured in the dynamic table and indexed into Elastic Kibana. Any help on this would really add great value for us in solution. Please see below how it is captured.

[{"dateweeklycomments":"2020-04-09T00:00:00.000Z","Teammember":"Roger Benny","Role":{"id":null,"name":"Agent"},"Hours Worked":**"5"**},{"dateweeklycomments":"2020-04-16T00:00:00.000Z","Teammember":"Roger Benny","Role":{"id":null,"name":"Agent"},"Hours Worked":**"10"**}]

Comment: Dynamic table? It would be helpful if you could add detail about reproducing your problem, or the inputs, what you have tried, what output you got, what output you were expecting.

Comment: @tomr thank you for responding, we have internal application in our org, in that app we have used fields and table.. we do not have control on how this data is indexed into Elastic but in Kibana we have the output which i have mentioned above.. all i want is to calculate total hours worked, for example in the above mentioned document, i have weekly Hours worked: 5 and Hours worked: 10 and i need total hours worked: 15

Comment: Since i am new to Kibana, i am sorry if i did not explain correctly, but this above example document is reflecting same in my variable and i need help in writing script to calculate the total hours worked as output please.

Comment: You probably want a sum aggregation ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html)).

Comment: @tomr - I am new to Kibana, could you please kindly help me with the code. Appreciate your time again.